# Pytorch: The accuracy stays the same

Tags: pytorch

The model:

```
class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inchannel, outchannel, stride=1):
        super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__()
        self.left = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(inchannel, outchannel, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(outchannel),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(outchannel, outchannel, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(outchannel)
        )
        self.shortcut = nn.Sequential()
        if stride != 1 or inchannel != outchannel:
            self.shortcut = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(inchannel, outchannel, kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(outchannel)
            )
            
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.left(x)
        out = out + self.shortcut(x)
        out = F.relu(out)
        
        return out

class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ResidualBlock, num_classes=1):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.inchannel = 64
       
        self.startconv= nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(4*16, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.layer1 = self.make_layer(ResidualBlock, 64, 2, stride=1)
        self.layer2 = self.make_layer(ResidualBlock, 64, 2, stride=2)
        self.layer3 = self.make_layer(ResidualBlock, 64, 2, stride=2)        
        self.layer4 = self.make_layer(ResidualBlock, 128, 2, stride=2)        
        self.fc = nn.Linear(128*64, num_classes)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        
    def make_layer(self, block, channels, num_blocks, stride):
        strides = [stride] + [1] * (num_blocks - 1)
        layers = []
        for stride in strides:
            layers.append(block(self.inchannel, channels, stride))
            self.inchannel = channels
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        raw = self.startconv(x[0])
        depth = self.startconv(x[1])
        Luv = self.startconv(x[2])
        YCrCb = self.startconv(x[3])
        x = torch.cat((raw, depth,Luv,YCrCb), 1)
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.layer1(out)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = self.layer3(out)
        out = self.layer4(out)
        # out = F.avg_pool2d(out, kernel_size=out.size()[2:]).view(out.size()[0],-1)
        out = F.avg_pool2d(out, 4)
        out = out.view(out.size()[0], -1)
        # out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out
def count_parameters(model):
    return sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)
```

The training and accuracy functions:

```
def validate(model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    model.eval()
    
    predictions = []
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        validation_batch_losses = []
        
        for (raw,depth,Luv,YCrCb, labels) in val_loader:
            raw = raw.reshape(len(raw),3,256,256)
            raw =raw/127.5 -1
            raw = raw.to(device)

            depth = depth.reshape(len(depth),3,256,256)
            depth =depth/127.5 -1
            depth = depth.to(device)

            Luv = Luv.reshape(len(Luv),3,256,256)
            Luv =Luv/127.5 -1
            Luv = Luv.to(device)

            YCrCb = YCrCb.reshape(len(YCrCb),3,256,256)
            YCrCb =YCrCb/127.5 -1
            YCrCb = YCrCb.to(device)

            labels = labels.to(device).to(torch.float32)
            images =[raw,depth,Luv,YCrCb]
            # images = torch.cat((raw, depth,Luv,YCrCb), 1)
            
            labels_pred = model(images).squeeze(1)
            loss = loss_fn(labels_pred, labels)
            validation_batch_losses.append(float(loss))
            mean_loss = statistics.mean(validation_batch_losses)
            
            
    return mean_loss

def accuracy(model, loader):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    
    model.eval()
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        for (raw,depth,Luv,YCrCb, labels) in train_loader:
            raw = raw.reshape(len(raw),3,256,256)
            raw =raw/127.5 -1
            raw = raw.to(device)

            depth = depth.reshape(len(depth),3,256,256)
            depth =depth/127.5 -1
            depth = depth.to(device)

            Luv = Luv.reshape(len(Luv),3,256,256)
            Luv =Luv/127.5 -1
            Luv = Luv.to(device)

            YCrCb = YCrCb.reshape(len(YCrCb),3,256,256)
            YCrCb =YCrCb/127.5 -1
            YCrCb = YCrCb.to(device)

            labels = labels.to(device)
            images =[raw,depth,Luv,YCrCb]
            # images = torch.cat((raw, depth,Luv,YCrCb), 1)
        
            labels_pred = model(images)
            # print(labels,labels_pred)
            _, predicted = torch.max(labels_pred.data, 1)
        
            total += labels.size(0)
            
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            
    return (100* correct / total) 

def train(model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    model.train()
    
    train_batch_losses = []
    
    for (raw,depth,Luv,YCrCb, labels) in train_loader:
        raw = raw.reshape(len(raw),3,256,256)
        raw =raw/127.5 -1
        raw = raw.to(device)

        depth = depth.reshape(len(depth),3,256,256)
        depth =depth/127.5 -1
        depth = depth.to(device)

        Luv = Luv.reshape(len(Luv),3,256,256)
        Luv =Luv/127.5 -1
        Luv = Luv.to(device)

        YCrCb = YCrCb.reshape(len(YCrCb),3,256,256)
        YCrCb = YCrCb/127.5 -1
        YCrCb = YCrCb.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device).to(torch.float32)
        images =raw
        images =[raw,depth,Luv,YCrCb]
        
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model(images).squeeze(1)
        
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        train_batch_losses.append(float(loss))
        
        mean_loss = statistics.mean(train_batch_losses)
        
    return mean_loss
```

The rest:

```
epochs = 100
batch_size = 8
learning_rate = 0.0001
model = ResNet(ResidualBlock).to(device)
print(count_parameters(model))
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
n_total_steps = len(train_loader)


train_losses = []
valid_losses = []

train_accuracies = []
valid_accuracies = []
for epoch in range(1, epochs +  1):
    
    print('Epoch: ', epoch)
    
    train_loss = train(model, criterion, optimizer)
    train_accuracy = accuracy(model, train_loader)
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    train_accuracies.append(train_accuracy)
    print('Training loss:', train_loss)
    print('Training accuracy: {}%'.format(train_accuracy))
    
    valid_loss = validate(model, criterion, optimizer)
    valid_accuracy = accuracy(model, val_loader)
    valid_losses.append(valid_loss)
    valid_accuracies.append(valid_accuracy)
    
    print('Validation loss:', valid_loss)
    print('Validation accuracy: {}%'.format(valid_accuracy))
```

Output:

Epoch:  1

Training loss: 0.5845869481563568
Training accuracy: 50.0%

Validation loss: 0.6932758688926697
Validation accuracy: 50.0%

Epoch:  2

Training loss: 0.19938108821709952
Training accuracy: 50.0%

Validation loss: 0.6861477096875509
Validation accuracy: 50.0%

I tried different losses, learning rates, batch sizes, models, datasets, etc...

**Please tell me if I forgot to provide something and I will upload it**

Comment: What's your class balance? In training and in validation?

Comment: 50/50 
2 classes

Comment: One comment: you're clearly overfitting as your training loss is going down but your validation is not. You said you have tried changing learning rates and batch sizes. Which range have you tried?

Comment: lr: 0.001 - 0.00001 
batch_sizes: 1 - 128

Comment: I don't follow enterily your accuracy computation, and why not using  https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/accuracy.html but - if I were you - I would put a breakpoint/print after `            _, predicted = torch.max(labels_pred.data, 1)` and check which values are in `predicted`. I suspect it's uniformly 0 or 1.

Comment: already did that: 
These are the results 

labels = tensor([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])

pred = tensor([[0.0319], [0.0312],  [0.0311],  [0.0314],  [0.0308], [0.0316],  [0.0322], [0.0319]])

basically you are right how can I fix this?

Comment: I think I found the culprit, check my anwser here below

Answer (score 0):

Per what you shared in your comments your predictions have a shape (bactch_size, 1) instead of (batch_size, 2). This value of 2 is needed to predict amongst two classes. This is because you did not configure your model to work with two classes, and the model defaults to `num_classes=1`.

Replace `model = ResNet(ResidualBlock).to(device)` by `model = ResNet(ResidualBlock, num_classes=2).to(device)`

edit:

If you don't want to set it to two classes and keep the sigmoid output (instead of a softmax with two classes), you could replace

```py
            _, predicted = torch.max(labels_pred.data, 1)
```

with

```py
            predicted = (labels_pred.data > 0.5).long()
```

which maps probabilities to 0 or 1 with a 0.5 threshold.

Comment: Yes I do have 2 classes but it's either a 1 or a 0 
I used BCEloss with sigmoid and still the same problem occurred.

Comment: Check my new proposal.